# PWA is working in google chrome but not firefox

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps

So, I've decided to make my website test into a PWA, and it works with google chrome but not firefox (mobile).

**I have this in my index.html head**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>MYWEBSITE</title>

    <!--Website Icon-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="images/favicon.svg">
    <link rel="alternate icon" href="images/favicon.png">

    <!--Stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!--PWA-->
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

**My manifest.webmanifest**

```
{
    "name": "Progressive Web App",
    "short_name": "Site",
    "description": "Stuff",
    "icons": [{
            "src": "/images/favicon.svg",
            "type": "image/svg+xml",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/favicon.svg",
            "type": "image/svg+xml",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        },
        {
            "src": "icon/fox-icon.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": "index.html",
    "background_color": "#000000",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#91e7ee"
}
```

**And sw.js**

```
// On install - caching the application shell
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('sw-cache').then(function(cache) {
            // cache any static files that make up the application shell
            return cache.add('index.html');
        })
    );
});

// On network request
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        // Try the cache
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            //If response found return it, else fetch again
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

I don't have anything else added to my code what else am I missing?
Cause I've searched and everything should but it doesn't?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a bit hard to figure out. Could you give more detail on what is happening? Are there any errors you are seeing in the console, etc.

Comment: So, I've decided to do more testing and it seems the PWA only works in my localhost (Im using USBWebserver) and when joining the site (either by hosting on same pc or in a website hosting service) the install progressive web app button won't appear

Comment: FireFox does not support beforeinstall prompt. You have to do it manually. On Android there is a little home icon in the address bar to indicate it can be added to the homescreen.

Not sure if that is what you are looking for or not.

Also, like was mentioned before, what qualifies as 'doesn't work'?